# Race condition in JWT

Tags: authentication, session, jwt

Reading several tutorials about using JWT for login/logout purposes in website/app, they all seem to suggest this mechanism of storing some user info (such as id, name, etc.) on the payload data, like (from official [website](https://jwt.io/introduction)):

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin": true
}
```

and then storing the token somewhere in the frontend and include it for every request (e.g., in the Authorization header after Bearer). But then this form of keeping track of the logged-in user can lead to a serious race condition for operations that change the payload data like login and logout. Here is a simple senario: Assume user with id 4 is already logged in and the token containing the user id payload is already stored in the frontend. Now the front app sends some requests and the following actions take place in chronological order:

| Action | JWT token stored in the frontend | login status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Front end sends request A asking for some arbitrary action | {id:4} | logged in |
| Front end sends request B asking to logout | {id:4} | logged in |
| The response of request B comes, carrying token with payload {} which means user is logged out | {} | logged out |
| The response of request A comes carrying token with payload {id:4} (same as its corresponding request) | {id:4} | logged in!!!!! |

So while user logged out, it got logged back in again without notice! This is because the response token of request A overwrites that of token B! In general this decentralize mechanism of storing any info on the jwt payload can lead to race condition as the incoming tokens can overwrite each other and changes (such as login status) could be lost. I guess we need to do more on either frontend or backend. Am I missing something about JWT?

Answer (score 0):

JWT token is generated and returned only on the response of the login request. On rest of the (action) calls, the JWT token is only sent to the backend, there is no new token received and updates at the client end. On logout, the token on the client end is cleared.

The race condition occurs only if between the login and logout requests then.

Ideally you cannot delete a JWT token since we do not store it on backend. Deletion is truly only when it expires. So a modified version of this model will maintain a list of all the logged out unexpired tokens in the backend for improved security. This can also help in avoiding the said race condition.

Comment: Yes, as you said we need to do some more action, like deleting the token on the front end ... but then it means JWT is no place to store session info as they may change. And this is against the JWT offical website [example](https://jwt.io/introduction) where they store the user name (John Doe as usual) in the JWT token. What if user updates his name?

Comment: a not on deleting, if the JWT token is stored in server managed cookie (that is cookie with httponly flag set), then the deleting can happen only when in the logout response the JWT stored cookie content is empty